# How to drop row from many to many relationship table in doctrine

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, many-to-many

Hi I have M:M relationship between two tables, Contacts and Tags and their M:M table is called Contacts_Tags:

```
Contacts
------------
ID
Name

Tags
-----------
ID
Name

Contacts_Tags
--------------
Contact_ID
Tag_ID
```

I have entities for Contacts called Contact and for Tags called Tag but not for Contacts_Tags table.

I want to drop row from `Contacts_Tags` only. This is my relationship in `Contact` Entity.

```
/**
 * Many Contacts have Many Tags.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="contacts", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Contacts_Tags",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Tag_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Contact_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}
 *      )
 */
private $tags;
```

I tried this query but it didn't help

```
$queryBuilder                    =  $this->entityManager->getRepository(Contact::class)->createQueryBuilder("o")
            ->leftJoin("o.tags", "ct")
            ->leftJoin(Tag::class, "t", "WITH", "t.ID", "ct.Tag_ID")
            ->where("t.Name = :tagName")
            ->delete("o.tags", "ct")
            ->setParameter(":tagName", $diffBeat)
        ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove it from the collection.

you can define a function in your Contact class like this:

```
function removeTag(Tag $tag)
{
   if($this->tags->contains($tag)){
      $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
   }
}
```

Afterwards persist your entity